# Express $\sin^3x$ in terms of cosines of multiples of $x$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am studying complex numbers, and I have been trying to figure that out. Just not getting it. I keep getting $\frac{1}{-i8 (2\cos(3x) - 2\cos(x) - i4\sin(x))}$.

Comment: The problem sounds undoable, because $\sin^3x$ is an *odd* function whereas $\cos kx$ is *even* for all $k$.  Any combination of even functions remains even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if your goal is to express $\sin^3(x)$ in terms of cosinus you can use that $\sin(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ so we get $\sin^3(x)=\cos^3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$. Notice that $\sin^3(x)$ is an odd function.

When you want to use complex numbers, we know the Euler's formula:

$$e^{\varphi i}=\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i$$

So, we get (using $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$):

$$e^{\varphi i}-e^{-\varphi i}=\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i-\cos(-\varphi)-\sin(-\varphi)i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{\varphi i}-e^{-\varphi i}=\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i-\cos(\varphi)+\sin(\varphi)i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{\varphi i}-e^{-\varphi i}=2\sin(\varphi)i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(\varphi)=\frac{e^{\varphi i}-e^{-\varphi i}}{2i}$$

The same way you can proof that $\cos(\varphi)=\frac{e^{\varphi i}+e^{-\varphi i}}{2}$.

Now, when we have $\sin^3(x)$ you only get it this way:

$$\sin^3(x)=\left(\frac{e^{\varphi i}-e^{-\varphi i}}{2i}\right)^3=\frac{\left(e^{\varphi i}-e^{-\varphi i}\right)^3}{\left(2i\right)^3}=\frac{3e^{-xi}-3e^{xi}-e^{-3xi}+e^{3xi}}{-8i}$$

Answer (score 0):

First use:
$$
\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\sin(x))^3&=\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^3\\
&=\frac{e^{3ix}-3e^{2ix}e^{-ix}+3e^{ix}e^{-2ix}-e^{-3ix}}{-8i}\\
&=\left(\frac{-1}{8i} \right) \left([\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)]-3[\cos(x)+i\sin(x)] \\
   \phantom{nn}+3[\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)-[\cos(-3x)+i\sin(-3x] \right)\\
&=\left(\frac{-1}{8i} \right)(i[2\sin(3x)-6\sin(x)])
\end{aligned}
$$
etc... but not in terms of cosines.